# rspec with Rails 4.2 undefined method `commit_records' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4.2

After upgrading from Rails 4.1 to Rails 4.2 I've got the following error while running `spec`:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `commit_records' for nil:NilClass
```

What's the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you use *test_after_commit* gem. Just upgrade to version >= `0.2.6`. There is [the fix](https://github.com/grosser/test_after_commit/pull/28/files).

At the moment of writing the most recent version is *0.4.0*. Feel free to use it:
`gem 'test_after_commit', '~> 0.4.0'`